# Buscar y encontrar un elemento en numpy y extraer el elemento "limpio"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

quería saber como puedo encontrar un elemento en un array bi dimensional de numpy, quiero hacer algo similar que hice con listas.

```
ruts = []
nombres = []
apellidos = []
edades = []
telefonos = []
diagnosticos = []
buscar_Rut = input("Ingrese el rut que desea buscar: ")
X=ruts.index(buscar_Rut)
print("----------------")
print("Rut:",ruts[X])
print("Nombre:",nombres[X])
print("Apellido:",apellidos[X])
print("Edad:",edades[X])
print("Telefono:",telefonos[X])
print("Diagnostico:",diagnosticos[X])
print("----------------\n")
```

probe con np.where pero me devuelve los valores en este formato:

```
(array([3], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
```

y no se como podria extraer esas coordenadas que me entrega el where.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongamos por ejemplo que queremos encontrar los elementos con valor 3 en el array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4], 
    [3,6,3,2], 
    [1,2,5,3]
])
```

Si usando `np.where()` buscamos los elementos que valen 3, el resultado será una tupla con dos elementos, el primero de ellos será la lista de filas y el segundo la lista de columnas, en que aparece el valor buscado:

```
>>> np.where(a==3)
(array([0, 1, 1, 2]), array([2, 0, 2, 3]))
```

Si lo que quieres es, por ejemplo, mostrar para cada aparición del 3, sus "coordenadas" dentro del array, puedes pasar ambos elementos de la tupla a la función `zip()`, así `zip(*np.where(a==3))`. El operador `*` causa el desempaquetado de la tupla retornada por `np.wehere()` en dos elementos separados, de modo que a `zip()` le estás pasando dos parámetros (el primero la lista de filas, el segundo la lista de columnas).

La función `zip()` retorna un generador sobre el que puedes iterar. En cada iteración obtienes una pareja, siendo el primer elemento tomado de la primera lista y el segundo elemento tomado de la segunda lista. Es decir, obtienes un par (fila,columna), justo lo que querías.

Entonces, el siguiente fragmento muestra un ejemplo que ayudará (espero) a comprenderlo:

```
for x,y in zip(*np.where(a==3)):
  print("El elemento a[{}, {}] vale {}".format(x, y, a[x,y]))
```

Que mostraría por pantalla:

```
El elemento a[0, 2] vale 3
El elemento a[1, 0] vale 3
El elemento a[1, 2] vale 3
El elemento a[2, 3] vale 3
```

Comment: genial me funciono perfecto!, como podria ahora ordenar estos elementos de mayor a menor?

Comment: ¿Qué elementos quieres ordenar? Los valores son todos iguales en este ejemplo (todos 3).  Los índices ya salen ordenados, primero por filas y luego en cada fila por columnas. No entiendo qué es lo que quieres ordenar.

Comment: supongamos que en vez de : zip(*np.where(a==3)): usas zip(*np.where(a!=0)): y obtienes multiples numeros distintos, como podria ordenar estos?.

Comment: Yo iteraría sobre ese zip y en vez de ir imprimiendo los resultados los iría guardando en una lista, para después ordenarla una vez terminado el bucle. Para el caso de buscar los elementos distintos de cero puedes usar `a.nonzero()` que te retorna lo mismo que `np.where(a!=0)`.